# HTML5 can't play mp4 video from blob

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, blob, indexeddb

I have a a  little bit complex website mechanism for loading video,
and I have tested it in several ways,

First I have these 2 videos

1. the first one is a very light video with only 20seconds duration and is not HD I think and it is even less than 1MB
2. the second one is a video clip that runs like 4 minutes and I think it is HD and the memories are like 90MB,

Both are in mp4 format

I have both of the videos in the server,

I tried to run those videos both in IE11 and Google Chrome by streaming them from the server with "video" tag in HTML5 and both of them runs very smooth (one video at a time)

Next, I tried to save the video in a client-side storage using IndexedDB so that in the future, the browser does not have to stream it anymore,

those videos are saved as blob and then stored inside the IndexedDB (except in the Google Chrome I have to save those videos or any files as ArrayBuffer as Chrome does not support the blob inside the indexedDB just yet),

When I load the video from the indexedDB, I convert the blob to an objectURL using createObjectURL() and play them in the video source, (for Google Chrome I have to load the arrayBuffer and then convert them first to blob)

While in IE11 both videos are running fine as usual,
but in Chrome I can only play the first video (the light one), as for the second video, it never played on Chrome! I have no idea how can this happen as the 2nd video plays well if it is streamed.

Here is the properties of both videos:
[image: video]

On the left is video with 89MB and the right is 300KB
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? or is it just not supported in Chrome for HD?

Comment: Dunno if it's directly related to your issue, but the chrome team is currently working on blob support for indexedDB since march, so if nobody can help you here, you may have to report the bug:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108012

Comment: Why not just let the browser manage its own cache?

Comment: Hey I don't have an answer for your question but I'm fascinated by your storage of video blobs in IDB. Can you share some code?

Comment: @buley it's just retrieving video from the server using AJAX and retrieve it as blob and save it using IDB, simple

Comment: How are you grabbing the raw bytes off the wire? XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @buley yes, and the responseType="blob"